# Trying to start an activity from broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create a lockscreen. When I try to start the  `com.fira.locker.LockScreenActivity` from the broadcastReceiver, I just get an error. The error says:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.setFlags(int)' on a null object reference
```

This is my code:

```
package com.fira.locker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Johannett321 on 10/04/16.
 */
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public String screenlockedNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //start activity
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.fira.locker",     "com.fira.locker.LockScreenActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not starting simple intent like this..

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, LockScreenActivity.class));
finish();
```

or you can try this..

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,LockScreenActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one worked. The first one doesn't work in a broadcastreceiver i think.

Comment: It will work, if we give context of the activity. 

BTW Your Problem is Solved?

Comment: Yes, my problem is solved. The problem wasn't even in the code i shared, it was in the LockScreenActivity class...

Answer (score 5):

Use this code. Hope it help you.

```
Intent i= new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LockScreenActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, @karimkhan **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** is work for me.