# startActivity not being brought to foreground from BroadcastReceiver (RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, android-permissions

I have the following scenario in my application. On start it opens and requests `RECORD_AUDIO` permissions and records 'x' many seconds of audio. And I want the application to run upon `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App_Test"
        android:exported="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true">

        <activity android:name="com.example.app_test.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.app_test.BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The MainActivity.kt looks like the following:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Define audio recording variables
    private val sampleRate = 44100
    private val channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
    private val audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
    private val audioPermission = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Toast.makeText(this, "I'm in MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Call the recordAudio() method to record audio
        recordAudio()
        // Finish and close the application.
        finishAndRemoveTask()
    }


    private fun recordAudio() {...}
```

And the BootReceiver.kt looks like so...

```
class BootCompletedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            val mainActivityIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Kotlin Device restarted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            mainActivityIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            Toast.makeText(context, "Flagg Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            context?.startActivity(mainActivityIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use a Handler() `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(...` to start the intent but this didn't work either.

Should I be using `BootCompletedReceiver` to start a service which starts the activity instead?
Looking at Logcat I can see that the MainActivity is being called it's just not being brought forward.

Any and all help is gratefully received. Thanks in advance!

I have tried to use a Handler() `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(...` to start the intent but this didn't work either.

I am seeing the following in the Logcat:

```
`2023-03-13 12:14:47.231   590-958   ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W  Background activity start [callingPackage: com.example.app_test; callingUid: 10122; isCallingUidForeground: false; callingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; callingUidProcState: TRANSIENT_BACKGROUND; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; realCallingUid: 10122; isRealCallingUidForeground: false; realCallingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; realCallingUidProcState: TRANSIENT_BACKGROUND; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: null; isBgStartWhitelisted: false; intent: Intent { flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.example.app_test/.MainActivity }; callerApp: ProcessRecord{11db762 2330:com.example.app_test/u0a122}]
2023-03-13 12:14:47.234   590-958   ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       E  Abort background activity starts from 10122`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to start an activity from broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815216/trying-to-start-an-activity-from-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: Hi @EliasFazel - It doesn't appear so